# Warning: : Undefined array key "username"

Tags: php

I want to insert 'username' and also 'level' into platform.

Here is the code.

For login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include('config.php');

$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? AND password = ?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($connect, $query);

if ($stmt) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $email, $password);
   
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        header('Location: ../app');
        $user = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
        $_SESSION['username'] = $user['username'];
        $_SESSION['level'] = $user['level'];
    } else {
        header('Location: ../index.php?error=1');
    }

    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    mysqli_close($connect);
} else {
    die("Error logs " . mysqli_error($connect));
}
?>
```

for sidebar.php (where i want to insert the username)

```
<div class="sidebar">
      <!-- Sidebar user panel (optional) -->
      <div class="user-panel mt-3 pb-3 mb-3 d-flex">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="img-circle elevation-2" alt="User Image">
        </div>
        <div class="info">
          <a href="#" class="d-block"><?php echo $_SESSION['username'].'|'.$_SESSION['level']?></a>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

And for index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<?php  session_start();
include('header.php');?>
<?php include('../conf/config.php');?>
<body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini layout-fixed">
<div class="wrapper">
  <aside class="main-sidebar sidebar-dark-primary elevation-4">

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <?php include('sidebar.php'); ?>
</aside>
</div>
```

I checked that $_SESSION['username'] is set before trying to display it in sidebar.php. Later I found that every time I enter the text from else.
Exemplu concret :

```
<div class="info">
    <?php if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) { ?>
        <a href="#" class="d-block"><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></a>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <a href="#" class="d-block">Name user</a> //He display this every time
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: set the `$_SESSION['name']` value.